# Adding shortcut key for Save layer edits in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, editing, save, shortcuts

Is there a shortcut key to save layer edits in QGIS? If not, how to create one then?

Comment: I do not see any by default, source: https://north-road.com/qgis-3-0-shortcuts/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS, go to Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts... -> search for "Edit" and you can set a shortcut since there is no default. For more infos: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings - Keyboard Shortcuts - Save Layer Edits, and choose one